# Why do I get HttpRequestException with HTTPClient? (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone, httpclient, httpresponse

I'm trying to make a Windows Phone app that automatically connect users on a certain Wi-Fi network.
This app has been already written in Java so what I'm trying to do is to "translate" the Java code in C#.

The Java code works fine, here it is:

```
List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("referer", "https://captive.unisa.it/main.htm"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("err_flag", "0"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));   
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("buttonClicked", "4"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_url", ""));

UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(FORM_URL);
httppost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);
Log.v(Utils.TAG, "Post done...checking response");
String strRes = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

if (strRes.contains(LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL_PATTERN)) {
    // login successful
    return 1;
} else {
    return 3;
}
```

The C# code doesn't. I get an exception on **response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();**

> System.Net.HttpRequestException: "Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)."

Here's the code:

```
try
{
    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("referer", "https://captive.unisa.it/main.htm"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("err_flag", "0"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", USERNAME),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", PASSWORD),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("buttonClicked", "4"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_url", "")
    };

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());       
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(FORM_URL, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));              
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();                       
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();   

    if (responseString.Contains(LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL_PATTERN))
    {

        lblAuth.Text = "OK!";
    }         
}
catch
{
    lblAuth.Text = "ERROR!";
}
```

Can you help me to try to figure out what's wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What value are you using for FORM_URL?

Comment: You got a 404, which means the url is not valid. If the url works in your browser, but not your code, then somethinga bout the server handling that url is detecting your 'bot' and blocking it.

Comment: Something goes wrong with your post request. Use some web debugging tool (for example, Fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and trace requests/responses of Java code and yours one. Then look for differences. ;)

Comment: @MarcB The URL works fine in my browser when I'm on the same Wi-Fi network. So why does it work on Android phones?

Anyway here's all the Java source code, maybe it can be useful:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fcapano/UnisaConnect/master/src/it/fdev/unisaconnect/wifilogin/LoginManager.java

Comment: @DanielHollinrake FORM_URL is a local URL, I don't think it's relevant becasue it's the same that works fine in the Java application. Anyway I published the full Java source code in the upper comment. Thank you both for your help! :)

Comment: somehow you're not replicating exactly what your browser is doing. e.g. maybe the server's doing UA detection. Maybe you're missing a generated field (e.g. there is some javascript in the page dynamically modifying the submitted form before it hits the wire).

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Ok, I'll try it! I posted the question because I thought the problem was easy to find with both the source codes. I'm installing Fiddler, let's see what happens! Thank you for the reply :).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the user-agent header to your request, e.g.:

```cs
if (client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("user-agent") == false)
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't test your code, but I came into situation when HttpClient did not set user-agent header (or it does not set it at all) and the webserver didn't like it.